# How can tweet my post on twitter with image from my blog listing page

Tags: javascript, twitter

Currently on my blog listing page displaying 10 posts with the pagination, from the blog listing page on bottom of the each post I have a tweet button to tweet my post.

Tweet button working properly with text, but I want to tweet my post with image from the blog listing page.

I could tweet a image from the post details page with the help of meta

But as per my client requirement from the blog listing page I should develop a functionality with image tweet.

Can any one help on this?

My current code:

```html
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"{count} data-text="image post" data-image="imae_url" data-via="webtricks" data-related="ladbrokes">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using the twitter card Implemented.